# ¿Cómo llamar código de Objective-c desde Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

He encontrado un código en `Objective-c` para que calcule la carga de la `cpu` pero esta en `Objective-c` y no se objective-c si no `Swift` he intentado pasarlo a Swift pero sin ningún resultado. Tampoco se como pasarlo a una función o algo y llamarla desde Swift.

PROBLEMA RESUELTO.
En el proyecto de swift crear un nuevo `fichero.m` que lo tenéis que enlazar en el `bridging-Header.h` y llamar desde el archivo swift `load()` y todo funcionara.

CODIGO RESEUELTO

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/processor_info.h>
#include <mach/mach_host.h>
    processor_info_array_t cpuInfo, prevCpuInfo;
mach_msg_type_number_t numCpuInfo, numPrevCpuInfo;
unsigned numCPUs;
NSTimer *updateTimer;
NSLock *CPUUsageLock;

void load() {
    int mib[2U] = { CTL_HW, HW_NCPU };
    size_t sizeOfNumCPUs = sizeof(numCPUs);
    int status = sysctl(mib, 2U, &numCPUs, &sizeOfNumCPUs, NULL, 0U);
    if(status)
        numCPUs = 1;

        CPUUsageLock = [[NSLock alloc] init];

    natural_t numCPUsU = 0U;
    kern_return_t err = host_processor_info(mach_host_self(), PROCESSOR_CPU_LOAD_INFO, &numCPUsU, &cpuInfo, &numCpuInfo);
    if(err == KERN_SUCCESS) {
        [CPUUsageLock lock];

        for(unsigned i = 0U; i < numCPUs; ++i) {
            float inUse, total;
            if(prevCpuInfo) {
                inUse = (
                         (cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_USER]   - prevCpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_USER])
                         + (cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM] - prevCpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM])
                         + (cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_NICE]   - prevCpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_NICE])
                         );
                total = inUse + (cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_IDLE] - prevCpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_IDLE]);
            } else {
                inUse = cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_USER] + cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM] + cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_NICE];
                total = inUse + cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_IDLE];
            }

            NSLog(@"Core: %u Usage: %f",i,inUse / total);
        }
        [CPUUsageLock unlock];

        if(prevCpuInfo) {
            size_t prevCpuInfoSize = sizeof(integer_t) * numPrevCpuInfo;
            vm_deallocate(mach_task_self(), (vm_address_t)prevCpuInfo, prevCpuInfoSize);
        }

        prevCpuInfo = cpuInfo;
        numPrevCpuInfo = numCpuInfo;

        cpuInfo = NULL;
        numCpuInfo = 0U;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error!");
    }
}
```

Comment: parece que  objectivec2swift tiene una restricción de 1 KB, en la salida

Comment: no se si esta pregunta entra dentro de la tematica de es SO, quizas con la etiqueta de revision de codigo. Saludos

Comment: Angel, requiere una reputación de 150 poner la etiqueta SO

Comment: no pero creo que si entra si la pregunta principal es ¿como llamar codigo de objetive-c desde switf?, creo que yo entendi mal y pense que querias generar el mismo codigo pero en switf. Saludos

Comment: quizas estos link lo puedan ayudar, mientras -> https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216 y este otro  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift quizas ayude tanto a usted o para crear una repuesta. Saludos

Comment: ya esta todo arreglado

Answer (score 3):

No es necesario que conviertas el código a Swift. Puedes utilizar Objective-C directamente en tu proyecto. A continuación te explico como lo he hecho yo.

**Primero de todo crea una clase llamada "CPUInfoManager" y selecciona como lenguaje Objective-C**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Cuando se haya creado, te preguntará si quieres crear un "bridging header". ¡Créalo!**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Ahora busca el fichero del bridging, por ejemplo "MyProject-Bridging-Header.h" y añade la siguiente línea**

```
#import "CPUInfoManager.h"
```

**A continuación, el fichero de interfaz (.h) déjalo como sigue**

```
//
//  CPUInfoManager.h
//  TestChart
//
//  Created by mhergon on 20/1/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Marc Hervera. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CPUInfoManager : NSObject

- (NSDictionary *)getCoresInfo;

@end
```

**Y el de implementación (.m) tal que así**

```
//
//  CPUInfoManager.m
//  TestChart
//
//  Created by mhergon on 20/1/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Marc Hervera. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CPUInfoManager.h"

#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/processor_info.h>
#include <mach/mach_host.h>

@implementation CPUInfoManager

processor_info_array_t cpuInfo, prevCpuInfo;
mach_msg_type_number_t numCpuInfo, numPrevCpuInfo;
unsigned numCPUs;
NSTimer *updateTimer;
NSLock *CPUUsageLock;

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        int mib[2U] = { CTL_HW, HW_NCPU };
        size_t sizeOfNumCPUs = sizeof(numCPUs);
        int status = sysctl(mib, 2U, &numCPUs, &sizeOfNumCPUs, NULL, 0U);
        if(status)
            numCPUs = 1;

        CPUUsageLock = [[NSLock alloc] init];

    }
    return self;
}

- (NSDictionary *)getCoresInfo {

    natural_t numCPUsU = 0U;
    kern_return_t err = host_processor_info(mach_host_self(), PROCESSOR_CPU_LOAD_INFO, &numCPUsU, &cpuInfo, &numCpuInfo);
    if(err == KERN_SUCCESS) {
        [CPUUsageLock lock];

        NSMutableDictionary *cpuInfoResult = [NSMutableDictionary new];

        for(unsigned i = 0U; i < numCPUs; ++i) {
            float inUse, total;
            if(prevCpuInfo) {
                inUse = (
                         (cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_USER]   - prevCpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_USER])
                         + (cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM] - prevCpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM])
                         + (cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_NICE]   - prevCpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_NICE])
                         );
                total = inUse + (cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_IDLE] - prevCpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_IDLE]);
            } else {
                inUse = cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_USER] + cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM] + cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_NICE];
                total = inUse + cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_IDLE];
            }

            NSString *coreKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", i];
            cpuInfoResult[coreKey] = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:inUse / total];
        }
        [CPUUsageLock unlock];

        if(prevCpuInfo) {
            size_t prevCpuInfoSize = sizeof(integer_t) * numPrevCpuInfo;
            vm_deallocate(mach_task_self(), (vm_address_t)prevCpuInfo, prevCpuInfoSize);
        }

        prevCpuInfo = cpuInfo;
        numPrevCpuInfo = numCpuInfo;

        cpuInfo = NULL;
        numCpuInfo = 0U;

        return cpuInfoResult;

    } else {

        NSLog(@"Error!");
        return nil;

    }

}

@end
```

**Ahora solo te queda utilizar esta nueva clase en una función Swift, por ejemplo**

```
func updateValues() {

    // Get Cores info
    let result = CPUInfoManager().getCoresInfo()
    print(result)

}
```

Resumiendo, puedes mezclar Objective-C y Swift sin problemas.

Comment: gracias, como podría sumar los valores que me devuelve el if y que me de el % de 100

Comment: Te contesto en el otro hilo que has creado